# Term limits extensions

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law

https://www.cnn.com/2020/09/10/politics/michael-cohen-trump-cnntv/index.html

What would need to happen in order to enable a US president to govern for a 3rd term?

Comment: A repeal of the 22nd Amendment. All attempts up to now have failed: [Twenty-second Amendment to the United States Constitution -  Attempts at repeal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-second_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Attempts_at_repeal)

Answer (score 4):

The two-term limit is embeded in the Constitution at the Twenty-Second Amendment.

A third term would therefore require a constitutional amendment to allow more than two terms. Under [Article V](https://www.archives.gov/federal-register/constitution/article-v.html), constitutional amendments can happen in one of two ways:

> The Congress, whenever two thirds of both houses shall deem it necessary, shall propose amendments to this Constitution, or, on the application of the legislatures of two thirds of the several states, shall call a convention for proposing amendments, which, in either case, shall be valid to all intents and purposes, as part of this Constitution, when ratified by the legislatures of three fourths of the several states, or by conventions in three fourths thereof.